# Query parameters AND and OR differentiation

Tags: rest, api, url-parameters

I want the following URLs:

- Get me players with names John and age 30
- Get me players with names John or Mary

So thinking:

- /players?names=John&age=30

But the second one. The "or" bit making me thing
 - `/players?names=John&name=Mary`

is wrong

and it should be:
 - `/players?names=John,Mary`

Note: I get the idea that pure REST doesn't care as URLs are supposed to be opaque but just thinking more API or pragmatic REST here.

Answer (score 2):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers, so long as the spelling conforms to the production rules defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

[Level 4 URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-1.2) support behaviors for encoding/extracting lists into a URI.  They can be made to work pretty much the way you illustrate in your second example `/players?names=John,Mary`, with some additional magic required to handle cases where the delimiters and reserved characters appear in the data.

You'll also see examples where a particular query name is repeated more than once: `/players?name=John&name=Mary`; [JAX-RS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipyw/index.html) is an example where this sort of spelling can be extracted into a `List` or a `Set`.

In some cases, you'll find examples where brackets `[]` are used to identify array parameters: `/players?name[]=John&name[]=Mary`.  That's [not RFC 3986](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/2542) compliant, but is based on an older specification that is now obsolete.

Comment: arrays in URLs are common, I never realised they where/are an apparently obsolete format

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly decided by how you handle the request in the server. Please be aware that many frameworks will consider `/players?names=John,Mary` to be a single element and not necessarily a list if you do not setup a matching URI pattern (e.g. take a look at [this discussion regarding micronaut](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1610)).

Nothing is stopping you from using the array param and treat it as OR. Just make sure you API documentation is clear.